# Installing wxPython from source under linux

Tags: python, build, dependencies, wxpython, installation

I am trying to install wxPython from source under linux. The steps I followed were:

1. Download wxPython from http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1.tar.bz2
2. Run `./configure --prefix=$HOME/Local`
   At the end of the configure process the output was:

   ```
   Configured wxWidgets 2.8.12 for `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'

     Which GUI toolkit should wxWidgets use?                 GTK+ 2
     Should wxWidgets be compiled into single library?       no
     Should wxWidgets be compiled in debug mode?             no
     Should wxWidgets be linked as a shared library?         yes
     Should wxWidgets be compiled in Unicode mode?           no
     What level of wxWidgets compatibility should be enabled?
                                          wxWidgets 2.4      no
                                          wxWidgets 2.6      yes
     Which libraries should wxWidgets use?
                                          jpeg               sys
                                          png                sys
                                          regex              sys
                                          tiff               builtin
                                          zlib               sys
                                          odbc               no
                                          expat              builtin
                                          libmspack          no
                                          sdl                no
   ```
3. `make` wxPython, which appears to run without errors.
4. `make install`

But when I now try to do `import wx` in the python console (v2.7), python does not find the module.

So my questions are:

1. Am I missing some dependencies although wxPython seems to build and install without any errors?
2. Did I miss anything during the installation process?
3. How do I make python aware of the new package?

Any hint, link, article is appreciated.

Comment: You've given it a custom installation directory, `~/Local` - is that on your Pythonpath?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I added `~/Local` to the pythonpath but `import wx` still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For wxPython 2.8.x, there are complete build from source instructions here:

http://wxpython.org/BUILD-2.8.html

If you'd rather go for 2.9, then you can use the following instructions instead: http://wxpython.org/builddoc.php

If you run into issues, join the wxPython-users mailing list / Google Group here: http://wxpython.org/maillist.php

Tell them which versions of wxPython and Python you're using along with which Linux and you'll almost certainly get help. There are a lot of Linux guys on there.

Answer (score -3):

I am installing  WxPython 3.0 on centos machine with python 2.7.

even with disable-mediactrl the install searches for GSTreamer and gives the error 
`"configure: error: GStreamer not available"` despite the fact that GSTreamer is available on the machine.

Here are the details for two such builds:

My idea was to turn OFF mediactrl, so I am using following option

```
python build-wxpython.py --extra_setup=disable-mediactrl  --build_dir=../bld
```

or

```
python build-wxpython.py --extra_setup="--disable-mediactrl  --build_dir=../bld
```

However, it still searches for GSTreamer and outputs the error message listed below.
I reinstalled GSTreamer 0.10 and into \usr\lib\GSTreamer 0.10, however, I receive the same error message

error message :

```
checking what is the type of the third argument of getsockname... socklen_t
checking what is the type of the fifth argument of getsockopt... socklen_t
checking for linux/joystick.h... yes
checking for python... /home/aptRoot/tools/python/64/Python-2.7/bin/python
checking for WEBKIT... configure: WARNING: webkitgtk not found.
configure: WARNING: WebKit not available, disabling wxWebView
checking for CAIRO... yes
checking for cairo_push_group... yes
checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 0.10 not available, falling back to 0.8
checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 0.8/0.10 not available.
configure: error: GStreamer not available
Error running configure
ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build-wxpython.py", line 378, in <module>
    wxbuild.main(wxscript, build_options)
  File "/home/hemadris/iAPT/install/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/build/tools/build-wxwidgets.py", line 364, in main
    "Error running configure")
  File "/home/hemadris/iAPT/install/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/build/tools/build-wxwidgets.py", line 80, in exitIfError
    raise builder.BuildError(msg)
BuildError
```